# make content appear at top of div of all 3 columns no matter what size they are

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to make sure that the content will appear at the top of the columns no matter how big they are (amount of content in each column). Ive removed the CSS which make all content aligned vertically in the middle, but then this messes the size and shape of the image..

Currently all the columns will be the same height no matter how much content is in each column, but the are vertical aligned... which means only the column which has the most content will be positioned up the top and the other with less content wont be... if I remove the css for either horizontal aligning or vertical aligning, all the pictures sizes get messed up.

```css
.round-image img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.testimonial-column {
  float: left;
  flex: 33.33%;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Vertical center alignment */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Horizontal center alignment */
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f5f5;
}


/* Clear floats after the three columns */

.testimonial-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
}

.testimonial-column img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 75%;
  max-height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
}

.testimonial-information p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.main-testi-info p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: italic;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.customer-location-testimonial p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.testimonial-large-image {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.testimonial-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-large-image">
  <div class="testimonial-row">
    <div class="testimonial-column">
      <div class="round-image">
        <img src="http://www.harlowfencing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/maintainedfencepanels-1170x878.jpg" alt="image1" />
        <div class="testimonial-information">
          <p> this is an example header which will be bold" </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /testimonial-information-->
        <div class="main-testi-info">
          <p> This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This
            is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is
            where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue
            to type out random letters and number
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /main-testi-info-->
        <div class="customer-location-testimonial">
          <p> Mr Doe </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /customer-location-testimonial-->
      </div>
      <!--  /round-image> -->
    </div>
    <!--  /testimonial-column  -->

    <div class="testimonial-column">
      <div class="round-image">
        <img src="http://www.harlowfencing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/maintainedfencepanels-1170x878.jpg" alt="image1" />
        <div class="testimonial-information">
          <p> this is an example header which will be bold" </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /testimonial-information-->
        <div class="main-testi-info">
          <p> This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This
            is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /main-testi-info-->
        <div class="customer-location-testimonial">
          <p> Mr Doe - </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /customer-location-testimonial-->
      </div>
      <!--  /round-image> -->
    </div>
    <!--  /testimonial-column  -->

    <div class="testimonial-column">
      <div class="round-image">
        <img src="http://www.harlowfencing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/maintainedfencepanels-1170x878.jpg" alt="image1" />
        <div class="testimonial-information">
          <p> this is an example header which will be bold" </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /testimonial-information-->
        <div class="main-testi-info">
          <p> This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This
            is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is
            where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue
            to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where
            a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a
            really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /main-testi-info-->
        <div class="customer-location-testimonial">
          <p> Mr Doe </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /customer-location-testimonial-->
      </div>
      <!--  /round-image> -->
    </div>
    <!--  /testimonial-column  -->
  </div>
  <!-- /grow -->
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

I have put this code in a jsfiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/84y0n6jt/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out a few lines of your css that is causing the undesired behavior:

```css
.round-image img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.testimonial-column {
  float: left;
  flex: 33.33%;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  --align-items: center;
  /* Vertical center alignment */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Horizontal center alignment */
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f5f5;
}


/* Clear floats after the three columns */

.testimonial-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 7%;
  margin-right: 7%;
}

.testimonial-column img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 75%;
  max-height: 75%;
  --width: 75%;
  --height: 75%;
}

.testimonial-information p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.main-testi-info p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: italic;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.customer-location-testimonial p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.testimonial-large-image {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.testimonial-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-large-image">
  <div class="testimonial-row">
    <div class="testimonial-column">
      <div class="round-image">
        <img src="http://www.harlowfencing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/maintainedfencepanels-1170x878.jpg" alt="image1" />
        <div class="testimonial-information">
          <p> this is an example header which will be bold" </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /testimonial-information-->
        <div class="main-testi-info">
          <p> This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This
            is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is
            where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue
            to type out random letters and number
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /main-testi-info-->
        <div class="customer-location-testimonial">
          <p> Mr Doe </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /customer-location-testimonial-->
      </div>
      <!--  /round-image> -->
    </div>
    <!--  /testimonial-column  -->

    <div class="testimonial-column">
      <div class="round-image">
        <img src="http://www.harlowfencing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/maintainedfencepanels-1170x878.jpg" alt="image1" />
        <div class="testimonial-information">
          <p> this is an example header which will be bold" </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /testimonial-information-->
        <div class="main-testi-info">
          <p> This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This
            is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /main-testi-info-->
        <div class="customer-location-testimonial">
          <p> Mr Doe - </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /customer-location-testimonial-->
      </div>
      <!--  /round-image> -->
    </div>
    <!--  /testimonial-column  -->

    <div class="testimonial-column">
      <div class="round-image">
        <img src="http://www.harlowfencing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/maintainedfencepanels-1170x878.jpg" alt="image1" />
        <div class="testimonial-information">
          <p> this is an example header which will be bold" </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /testimonial-information-->
        <div class="main-testi-info">
          <p> This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This
            is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is
            where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue
            to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where
            a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and number This is where a really long paragraph will go This is where a
            really long paragraph will go This is where a really long paragraph will go I ill continue to type out random letters and
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /main-testi-info-->
        <div class="customer-location-testimonial">
          <p> Mr Doe </p>
        </div>
        <!--  /customer-location-testimonial-->
      </div>
      <!--  /round-image> -->
    </div>
    <!--  /testimonial-column  -->
  </div>
  <!-- /grow -->
```